# Installing Java plugin for Chrome in Ubuntu

Tags: java, google-chrome, ubuntu

I do have JDK, everything works fine in Ubuntu, I mean IDE, some apps, I'm able to develop and run projects, but I got a message in Chrome: `Java(TM) is required to display this content`

I need to run this applet. How do I do that? I need to run it in Chrome because of the GWT plugin installed here. Should I add some parameters in a script, that would run it? Or is there another way? I saw links that proposed to install Java plugin for Chrome in Windows and Mac, but not Linux. Thanks in addvance.

I made a link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/libnpt.so` in `/opt/google/chrome/plugins`, it didn't help (well, it's not `libnpjp2.so`, which is recommended for this case, but it's the closest one I saw there).

**Update**: I found `libnpjp2.so` on my machine, the following command helped: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so /opt/google/chrome/plugins/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/44827/how-do-i-get-java-support-on-google-chrome-in-linux):

> Yes, add --enable-plugins to your chrome command. It's currently not
>   considered stable, but it works for me.
>
> Actually, it seems to just work without that. Have you tried it? You
>   can find a test applet here. Presumably you'll need Sun's Java
>   installed.

**UPDATE:** see the link for further  details. Lots of helpful answers.

Comment: Well, probably this plugin need to be installed before enabling it

Comment: @johnDoe there is a reason i posted the link. did you go through the answers over there?

Answer (score 13):

Current Chrome version do not requires more this option.

To install [java plugin for browsers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java), if you're using packaged java, install one of the following packages according you java version:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

To check you version, open a terminal (command line) and type:

```
java -version
```

Java 1.6 will require `icedtea6-plugin`, Java 1.7 `icedtea-7-plugin`.

Comment: How should I decide which one to install?

Comment: @IanHunter: based in your java version.

Comment: Consider that icedtea plugin depends on opendjdk which is (obviously) not SUN jdk

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 13.04 x64 ,

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

is working great. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I found, (none of these suggestions worked for me), is as followings:
First install Icedtead pluging by:

1. sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin

Then in your chrome browser go to:

1. chrome-> Settings-> Show Advanced Settings-> Privacy then click on
   Content Settings -> Plug-ins then click on Disable Individual Plug-in
2. Disable both "IceTea-Web Plugin" and "Java(TM)"
3. Restart the browser.
4. chrome-> Settings-> Show Advanced Settings-> Privacy then click on Content Settings -> Plug-ins then click on Disable Individual Plug-in
5. Enable only "IceTea-Web Plugin"
6. Enjoy !

Comment: I did sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin but I can't see icedTea-Web plugin in the list, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to run java plugin since chrome stops support http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI plugins

Answer (score 0):

Still good for Opera 12.16 & Ubuntu 14.04, but need to install both Icedtea's to get applets work

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin icedtea-6-plugin
```